# How can I add Angular2 code within pulled JSON data?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to add Angular2 specific code to a button pulled in json format from a CMS backend into an angular frontend.

The JSON data that is being pulled is like so:

```
{
  "value": "<p>Lorem Ipsum blah blah <a (click)=\"doMyThing()\">Do It!</a> more lorem ip...</p>",
}
```

Because this is requested AFTER Angular has loaded the main page, it is rendered in the browser as so:

```
"<p>Lorem Ipsum blah blah <a>Do It!</a> more lorem ipsum...</p>"
```

Does anyone know a way to keep (or re-add) the Angular Specific `(click)=` part of the code?

Comment: Use renderer2 to add elements to Dom using elementRef

Answer (score 0):

Use as inner HTML:

```
// HTML
<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml(htmlString)" ></div>

import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// In constructor 
constructor(private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}

safeHtml(htmlString: string) {
  return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlString);
}
```

Comment: ok, so it spits it out correctly, but the functionality isn't there (I guess Angular isn't registering it and adding the `_ngcontent` retrospectively)?